# All packages are installed in fresh python venv

Tags: pip, python-venv

So assume I have a folder `main` and I run

```
python -m venv vir_env/
source vir_env/Scritps/activate

(vir_env)
pip list
```

it lists all my installed packages, and not just `pip` and `setuptools`.

Is there a way to get a "clean" venv?

I am running windows 10, using GitBash as terminal

Comment: What python version? System packages should not be getting inherited by default. Try running `which pip` to make sure you're actually hitting the `pip` inside your virtual env, maybe the path didn't get adjusted properly?

Comment: Separately, I'd highly recommend WSL2 if you're doing linux dev stuff on windows.

Comment: Im running version 3.7.7. I am using WSL2, but since it is on my corporate PC, everything is on the network-drive, and there is some issues with the mounting of the network drives etc.

Comment: but you are right, the `vir_env` does not redirect the pip - it is using the "standard" pip. Maybe it is because I'm not sudo user, thus the `venv` is limited in the setup ?

Comment: Is `python` within the virtualenv at least? You could just use `python -m pip` if that's the case. Also try inspecting the `PATH` to see why the virtualenv isn't taking precedence.